# iphone app is crashing while assigning a string value to the table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, cfstring

i my iphone app while assigning a string value to the table view its crashing, i have the following code in cellForRowAt index path method

while assigning a string value to the table view

```
NSMutableArray *arrTrimmedTblData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableString *strTrimmedTblData;
for(int intVar=0;intVar<[array count];intVar++)
{

    strTrimmedTblData = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:intVar]];
    [strTrimmedTblData replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"("  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedTblData length])];
    [strTrimmedTblData replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")"  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedTblData length])];
    [strTrimmedTblData replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" "  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedTblData length])];
    [strTrimmedTblData replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\""  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedTblData length])];
    [strTrimmedTblData replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedTblData length])];
    [arrTrimmedTblData addObject:strTrimmedTblData];
}

NSLog(@"arrTrimmedTblData:%@",arrTrimmedTblData);
NSLog(@"arrTrimmedTblData:%@",[arrTrimmedTblData objectAtIndex:0]);
NSString *cellValue = [arrTrimmedTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

its crashing at this line   `cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;`

crash log:  variable cellValue is not a CFString

please any buddy do help me, thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allocated your cell with an instance of UITableViewCell ?

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusableCell];
```

or

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reusableCell] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by changing

```
NSString *cellValue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTrimmedTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *cellValue = [[arrTrimmedTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
 crashing Due To That Object is Not Available.
 I Hope It Will Work...
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

replaceOccurrencesOfString method return NSString object. So, you have to store return string in another string variable.